# How to keep Html file and its php file in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am very new to PHP , but i want to show a html page and handle it with and .php file in codeigniter, How can i do it. 
Example could be like this : 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_post

I tried to do the same but in controller if i try to run the html file it works fine but as i click on submit and try to fetch values it give my errors.

i do:
1. Made 2 file in view namely: Test.html and Test_Values.php
in Test.html i keep : the code as mentioned in w3 link
and in Test_Value.php I wrote the logic.

2.In controller i calls : $this->load->view("Test.html"); 
it shows me my html page but as i click on the submit button it says 404 page not found.

Please help me. What am i doing wrong??

Comment: What url u put in the action?

Comment: Better to use http://www.codeigniter.com/docs  and look at form helper http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html and form validation http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/index.html

Comment: Views should be in .php http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html and controllers http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you will have to put your logic in a function in your controller and not a separate `.php` file. e.g:

```
class Yourcontrollername extends CI_Controller{
    ...

    function form_processor(){...}

}
```

Then You are supposed to give the address and the name of the function which is going to process the form you sumbitted in the **action** attribute of your form! e.g:

```
<form action="yourControllerName/form_processor" method="post">
```

Finally, you really need to have to study the [Codeigniter Manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/)

Comment: Only class name and file name should be first letter upper case. In codeigniter 3

Comment: Both doc's of codeigniter here now CI3 and CI2 user guides http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Comment: You mean i should give the logic in one function and then refer it in action 
public function form_Preprocessor{
echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"];
}

I will give a try to .. and let you know soon :) Thankss

Comment: instead of `<form action="yourControllerName/form_processor" method="post">` 
`<form action="form_processor" method="post">`  Worked for me.